# lualatex: emergency stop when including a file from subfolder and setting aux/output directories

Tags: luatex, miktex

I have a main file including many files from the same subfolder. I get `lualatex` working in case:

1. I include the files from the subfolder and let the aux/pdf files be generated in the main directory
2. I don't include any file from the subfolder and set the directories aux/output to different subfolders.

However, when I include files from the subfolder and set aux/output directories I got an error

> Emergency stop. \include{SourceFiles/Ch2_Literature}
>
> I can't write on file `SourceFiles/Ch2_Literature.aux'. \include{SourceFiles/Ch2_Literature}

where I don't understand why it looks for `aux` file in the subfolder instead of the `aux-directory` I already set.

Comment: hard to say with this amount of information, but probably you need to generate a `SourceFiles` subdirectory of your specified aux folder (really redirecting aux files always causes far more trouble than its worth, it almost always breaks something and has no actual benefits)